# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SINGLE_SHEET') - AG-Grid-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

When importing **import 'ag-grid-enterprise';** in index.js Im getting this Error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SINGLE_SHEET')

Comment: can you please share your code and error ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. in your package.json make sure your ag grid community , ag grid react and ag grid enterprise are all the same version. They must not have carrots in front of the version numbers or a similar non-major version may be installed by npm.